# Make a function to print something depending the parameter

Tags: php

I want to create a function that the parameter takes the values 'on' and 'off'

```
public function test(on || off) {
    if isset[test(on);] -> {echo "test";}
    if isset[test(off);] -> {echo "test"; echo "<br>"; echo "great";}
}
```

the end result I'd like to be:

```
public function test(on || off) {
    if isset[test(on);] -> {function1();}
    if isset[test(off);] -> {function1(); echo "<br>"; function2();}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define("ON",1);
define("OFF",0);
//from here you can use ON or OFF in your program

function test($param = OFF) { //default state if not supplied will be OFF
if($param == ON){
    function1();
}else{
    function1();
    echo "<br>";
    function2();
}
}

test(ON); //will callfunction 1
test(OFF); // will call function1 echo br call function 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `isset()` is used to identify if a variable or array element is defined or not.  Also note that `on` and `off` are not predefined in PHP.

The best way I can translate what your pseudo code shows is:

```
<?php

function test($testing) {
        if ($testing) {
                function1();
        }
        else {
                function1();
                echo "<br>";
                function2();
        }
}

// called as test(true) or test(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be like that:

```
public function test($mode) {
    if($mode=='on'){
        function1();

    }elseif($mode=='off'){
        function1();
        echo "<br>";
        function2();
    }
    else{
        die('Error: Only "on" and "off" permitted for test');
    }
}
```